# Fill data into expandable rows of table with depth=3

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm searching for a solution for a seemingly easy task, which I simply can't solve:

I have a nested data structure of Years -> Months -> Events, which I'm trying to fill into a table with expandable rows, aka the parent-row is the aggregation of the child row.

The problem arises of the amount of depthness I need being three: I simply can't find any way to itereate through the table at the third level, as I can't use div, and can't use a nested tr or tbody as well. Solution is bound to bootstrap 3 and angularjs 1.5.

Hopefully someone has a good idea.

Table

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
     <th></th>
     <th>{{I18n.i18n('label.period')}}</th>
     <th>{{I18n.i18n('label.failure-duration')}}</th>
     <th>{{I18n.i18n('label.availability')}}</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody ng-repeat="year in data">
     <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'.a'+year.period}}">
        <td><div>&gt;</div></td>
        <td>{{year.period}}</td>
        <td>{{year.duration}}</td>
        <td>{{year.availability}}</td>
     </tr>

     <tr ng-repeat="month in year.months" class="{{'collapse a' + year.period}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'.'+month.period+year.period}}">
        <td><div>&gt;</div></td>
        <td>{{month.period}}</td>
        <td>{{month.duration}}</td>
        <td>{{month.availability}}</td>
     </tr>

     <!-- Iterating here obiously doesn't work because of variable scope and position in the table-->
     <tr ng-repeat="event in month" class="{{'collapse a' + +month.period+year.period}}">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{event.period}}</td>
        <td>{{event.duration}}</td>
        <td></td>
     </tr>


  </tbody>
```

Examplary data:

```
{
            period : '2021',
            duration : '647 Minutes',
            availability : '99,78978%',
            months : [
               {
                  period : 'January',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'February',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'March',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'April',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'May',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'June',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'July',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'August',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'September',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'October',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'November',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },{
                  period : 'December',
                  duration : '132 Minutes',
                  availability : '99,99458%',
                  events : [
                     {
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },{
                        period : '12.01. 12:34 - 12.01. 12:46',
                        duration : '24 Minutes',
                     },
                  ]
               },
            ]
         }
```

Comment: I have a solution, but I'm not sure what you intend when you've already looped through all the months - which events did you want to display under those months?

Comment: @Kinglish  The years show aggregated data and expand the month rows, the months show aggregated data and expand the single event rows. Like: level 1: years[x]; level 2: years[x].months[y]; level 3: years[x].months[y].events[z]

Answer (score 0):

Would this kind of thing be possible?

```
$scope.events=[];
$scope.setMonthForEvents = function(i) {
  $scope.events=$scope.year.months[i].events;
}

<tr  ng-repeat="month in year.months track by $index" class="{{'collapse a' + year.period}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'.'+month.period+year.period}}" ng-click="setMonthForEvents($index)">
    <td><div>&gt;</div></td>
    <td>{{month.period}}</td>
    <td>{{month.duration}}</td>
    <td>{{month.availability}}</td>
 </tr>

 <tr ng-repeat="event in events">
    <td></td>
    <td>{{event.period}}</td>
    <td>{{event.duration}}</td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no ng-container in angular 1.5

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it didn't really work; But I found another solution with ng-repeat-start and -end